# How do I change column names in list of data frames inside a function?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I know that the answer to "how to change names in a list of data frames" has been answered multiple times. However, I'm stuck trying to generate a function that can take any list as an argument and change all of the column names of all of the data frames in the list. I am working with a large number of .csv files, all of which will have the same 3 column names. I'm importing the files in groups as follows:

```
# Get a group of drying data data files, remove 1st column
files <- list.files('Mang_Run1', pattern = '*.csv', full = TRUE)
mr1 <- lapply(files, read.csv, skip = 1, header = TRUE, colClasses = c("NULL", NA, NA, NA))
```

I will have 6 such file groups. If I run the following code on a single list, the names of the columns in each data frame within the specified list will be changed correctly.

```
for (i in seq_along(mr1)) {
  names(mr1[[i]]) <- c('Date_Time', 'Temp_F', 'RH')
}
```

However, if I try to generalize the function (see code below) to take any list as an argument, it does not work correctly.

```
nameChange <- function(ls) {
  for (i in seq_along(ls)) {
    names(ls[[i]]) <- c('Date_Time', 'Temp_F', 'RH')
  }
  return(ls)
}
```

When I call `nameChange` on mr1 (list generated from above), it prints the entire contents of the list to the console and does not change the names of the columns in the data frames within the list. I'm clearly missing something fundamental about the inner workings of R here. I've tried the above function with and without `return`, and have made several modifications to the code, none of which have proven successful. I'd greatly appreciate any help, and would really like to understand the 'why' behind the problem as well. I've had considerable trouble in the past handling functions that take lists as arguments.

Thanks very much in advance for any constructive input.

Comment: *"it prints the entire contents of the list to the console and does not change the names of the columns in the data frames within the list"*  It sounds like you are not assigning the result. You need to do `mr1 <- nameChange(mr1)` to assign the result. You could also save it to a new object, `mr1_named <- nameChange(mr1)`.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in your question, why not just use `setnames()` within lapply? Similar to @Aron Boettcher 's example:
`lapply(Your_list, function(x) setnames(x, old = names(x), new =c(new_names))`

Comment: @Gin_Salmon `names <-` vs `setNames` are two ways to do the same thing... I don't think it's the real issue here.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know about the setnames() function.  Even simpler.

Comment: Either way, learning to use      lapply() and defining your own functions for use within the apply() group is challenging when you are new to R*, but the rewards are huge.

Comment: `lapply(some_list, setNames, c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"))` is the idiomatic way to write this code.

Comment: @shayaa I think the issue he is having is with how / what is being called within the loop, and how/ what is being outputed from the loop. The way our questioner has it written, he's renaming the element of a list rather than the dataframe contained at that index of the list. If he were to take that element of the list and put it into a dataframe, say  x <- ls[[i]], then names(x)<-c(list of names), then add x to a new list, it would work. But this is a perfect example of why to avoid for loops in R. The array function equivalent is far more efficient.

Comment: I can't reproduce OP's error...  `list_of_df <-replicate(10,data.frame(matrix(rnorm(15),5)), simplify = FALSE)`

`change_list_of_df_names <- function(some_list) {
  for(i in seq_along(some_list)){
    names(some_list[[i]]) <- c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")
  }
  return(some_list)
}`

`change_list_of_df_names(list_of_df)`

Comment: FYI for loops are not inefficient relative to non-vectorized *apply family of functions. Rather, R code that is vectorized is commonly implemented in C or Fortran. The `names` function is such as example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136402/discussion-between-aron-boettcher-and-shayaa).

Comment: @Gregor - You are exactly right. This is definitely the problem I was having. Very embarrassing. Thanks very much for the clarification. And yes, everyone suggesting the apply family approaches is also correct. I had tried these approaches but was not re-assigning the original list. Very dumb mistake. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this might be a very simple fix:
First, generalize the function you are using to rename the columns. This only needs to work on one dataframe at a time.

```
 renameFunction<-function(x,someNames){
      names(x) <- someNames
      return(x)
     }
```

Now we need to define the names we want to change each column name to.

```
someNames <- c('Date_Time', 'Temp_F', 'RH')
```

Then we call the new function and apply it to every element of the "mr1" list.

```
lapply(mr1, renameFunction, someNames)
```

I may have gotten some of the details wrong with regards to your exact sitiuation, but I've used this method before to solve similar issues. Since you were able to get it to work on the specific case, I'm pretty sure this will generalize readily using **lapply**

Comment: Thanks gregor. You are correct and I was being quick and dirty.

Comment: `renameFunction` already exists in R under the name `setNames`. Its implementation code even looks identical (minus the unnecessary `return`).